# Are there any NoSQL DBMS's that can work with Visual Basic 6/.net? If there are then how do I make it happen?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, nosql, database

I've tried working with OrientDB but it seems inserting to the database is not supported by the REST interface. Looking at Cassandra and MongoDB, they seem to be alright but I haven't seen any references to VB in their site.

Comment: OrientDB supports it. Just put your JSON document using HTTP POST: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/OrientDB_REST#POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like most solutions are in their infancy. On top of that, the majority of the .NET examples and solutions are typically written in C#. Here are some things I found.

From the docs this looks like it will be the best bet (Looks well supported).
http://github.com/atheken/NoRM

A simple tutorial written in VB for the project below
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/time-to-try-mongodb

http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/downloads
(Created for C#, but can reference via .NET in VB as described in the tut above.)

Comment: The C# library did it for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I know [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) speaks JSON over HTTP, so VB should be able to interact with it that way.

I haven't played with others, but if they expose a RESTful web service in some sort of reasonably easily-parseable format (XML, JSON, etc.), they should be relatively simple to deal with even if they don't ship with an "official" library. Just use whatever facilities VB has for dealing with HTTP and JSON/XML/whatever.